# UIAlertView cancel button return back to first view

Tags: xcode

I'm using Xcode 4.2 with storyboard.

My storyboard has navigation controller and root view, with a button on root view.
I set the button to push to a second view controller.
On click button, a pop up appears with Ok and Cancel button. If user clicks ok, it goes to second view.
But how to I make the Cancel button to go back to root view?

Here's my code to check on which button is clicked.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
  if (buttonIndex==0) // cancel button{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES]; // to go back to root view but not working
 }
}
```

Comment: can you put some code regarding what actually happens when you click button?

Answer (score 1):

You Can use this.
maybe can help.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
  if (buttonIndex==0) // cancel button{
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code however it didn't work. On clicking on the Cancel, it still shows the 2nd view. The code I posted, this method is invoked on the root view controller.m file.

Comment: just add [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; in your if stament

Comment: Bagus, I followed your advice but it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In your code , just dismiss the Alert View , when

```
(buttonIndex==1)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question. Button is at root view, on clicking it, what it will bring user to the second view at the beginning. Then the alertview pops up. So how do I set the Cancel button to navigate the user back to root view from second view.

Comment: Then you can pop from the controller to the root view controller instead.

Comment: how do I do that to pop from the 2nd controller to the root view controller? The method alertview that I posted is in the root view controller.m file itself.